# combining images into timelapse movie

Tags: video, jpeg, mencoder, timelapse

I was going through the steps listed in:

> [How can I combine 30,000 images into a timelapse movie?](https://superuser.com/questions/249101/how-can-i-combine-30-000-images-into-a-timelapse-movie)

When I run the mencoder command, I get an error saying:

```
[mf] search expr: *.jpg
============ Sorry, this file format is not recognized/supported =============
=== If this file is an AVI, ASF or MPEG stream, please contact the author! ===
Cannot open demuxer.
```

Anyone help me out with why it isn't recognizing the `.jpg` files?

Comment: What is the actual command you are running?

Comment: Have you tried ffmpeg? I just blogged about this (although I didn't test with that many input files): http://www.dsebastien.net/2015/01/25/simple-time-lapse-using-ffmpeg/

Answer (score 1):

You could try out a program called 'chronolapse' which worked great for me when combining 80k+ images.

It's free and open source.
You can get it here:

> http://keeyai.com/projects-and-releases/chronolapse/