# Record a time-lapse screen-capture directly in ffmpeg

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, screen-capture, timelapse

Can I use ffmpeg to record my Xorg desktop (without audio) at one frame a second into a video file that will play back the frames at 30 frames per second without requiring a conversion process?

The following command records my left display at 1 frame per second but the resulting video will advance the video frame once per second.

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -f x11grab -s 1920,1080 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -threads 0 out.mkv
```

Known alternatives:

1. [Make screenshots at an interval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247935/automatically-take-screenshot-of-specific-display-in-x/247936#247936), then combine videos [using mencoder](https://superuser.com/a/249141/38668)
2. As #1 but using [ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/782520/38668)
3. [Record a video of the desktop with ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop) at 1 fps or less, if the encoder supports such numbers and [speed up the video afterwards via ffmpeg](http://www.hdslr-cinema.com/news/workflow/convert-between-framerates/).

If it is not possible with `ffmpeg` alone, would a combination of `import` and `ffmpeg` or some other tools allow the time-leap video to be ready as quickly as possible after ending the recording?

Comment: Is there a super need for this, like making sped up demo or how-to videos or something?

Answer (score 12):

This should work:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -f x11grab -s 1920,1080 -i :0.0+0,0 -vf settb=\(1/30\),setpts=N/TB/30 -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -threads 0 out.mkv
```

EDIT: escaped parentheses from the shell

Comment: With the command from this answer will be 1 screenshot per second taken, shown later at 30 fps - resulting in 30x speedup. In case you want more, you can e.g. use `-framerate 0.5`, resulting in a 60x speedup, still shown at 30 fps.

Comment: It would be nice, if you could elaborate on the options. Or omit them if not needed for a MWE.

Comment: i'm trying to record at 1 frame per 3 seconds, but when the recording starts I get the message `The driver changed the time per frame from 1000/333 to 1/5` i.e. it sped it up from 0.333fps to 5fps which is *not what I want*! How do I force it to record a slower frame rate?