# How to stop ffmpeg from recording faster frame rate than specified?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, timelapse

I'm trying to record a time lapse using ffmpeg.  My input settings are:

```
ffmpeg -y -f v4l2 -input_format yuyv422 -framerate 0.333
```

I have tried to create both x264 and x265 output in an mp4 file.

But when the recording starts, I get this message:

```
The driver changed the time per frame from 1000/333 to 1/5
```

This results in the frame rate being sped up *15 times* what I asked for!  5fps is the actual frame rate the device is sending, but I thought I could get ffmpeg to basically record at a slower frame rate per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1019703/121080), so why isn't it working?

For what it's worth, I'm trying to record uncompressed (yuyv422) and compress it directly to the final output format directly for maximum quality, and I don't want to insert any additional steps like "record at a higher frame rate and then sample it down later".

Answer (score 0):

It seems the input frame rate can't be used to create a time lapse when the input is a device.  Instead, the frames have to be dropped on the output.  I created an output filter:

```
-vf select="not(mod(n\,15))",settb=\(1/30\),setpts=N/TB/30 -r 30
```

So my full command looked something like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -f v4l2 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video5 -vf select="not(mod(n\,15))",settb=\(1/30\),setpts=N/TB/30 -r 30 ...
```